# Execute stored procedure from java sending n parameters but in the database wait n+1

Tags: java, database, oracle, stored-procedures

I have next questions: I can execute sp from java sending 5 parameters but in the database wait 6?

Is possible only sending 5 and don't show error the moment the execute?

Example

```
CallableStatement statement = null;
String str = "{ call OWNER.NAMESTOREPROCEDURE (?,?,?,?,?)}";
try{
    statement = getConnection().prepareCall(str);
    statement.setInt(1, value);
    statement.setString(2, value);
    statement.setInt(3, value);
    statement.registerOutParameter(4, OracleTypes.NUMBER);
    statement.registerOutParameter(5, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
    statement.execute();
    int error = statement.getInt(4);
    if(error == 0){

    }else{

    }
}catch(SQLException e){
    ...
}
```

But sp wait 6 parameters.

Thanks!

Comment: did you tried to execute it?

Comment: What is the procedure specification? Why don't you want to pass all the arguments - is there one that defaults, or is an out parameter you just don't care about? If it's going to error why would you just hide that?

Comment: Yes, I try execute. @YCF_L

Comment: so did you get any error?

Comment: Because of moment it production and changes of software and database  not at the same time, and first execute change in database and update my sp I have much error and execute first change in software same case, for this razon i want manage the errors since software, I don´t create new sp. Thanks! @AlexPoole

Comment: Yes, wait 6 parameters and only send 5.

Comment: OK, that's a process problem, not a code problem. You should be coordinating database and application updates, surely? You *could* trap and ignore the exception from the call, but (a) that means your application just isn't doing what it was supposed to, and (b) if there's some other problem you'd hide that too (and not do what you were supposed to).

Comment: You could also make your database changes with this in mind; if you add an argument to your procedure, also add a wrapper procedure (with only 5 arguments) that calls the real one (with 6), if you can set a sensible default sixth argument value. Or just set a default for the sixth argument in your real procedure perhaps.

Comment: Sure coordinating, 
but there is some way to run the stored procedure as I put it?

Comment: @5frags - not unless you have a wrapper or default values, no. If it's erroring now then you need to change the application or the database.

Comment: First situation, any link for more information, i want learn more. Thanks